# Mongoose 5.3.1 ofFail() helper issues

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

After reading this blog post (below), I wanted to use the .orFail() helper function in one of my projects.

http://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-53-orfail-and-global-toobject.html

When the function findById() fails, it throws the exception indicated in the .orFail() function. However, when it doesn't fail, it returns "undefined" instead of the actual model object.

```
let tenants = await Tenant.findById(req.params.tenantId).orFail(new Error(`ID "${req.params.tenantId}" not found`))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. I was able to reproduce this and opened an issue with mongoose: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7099.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was confirmed as a bug. It's now fixed on 5.3.2

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7099